# How do you grab an element relative to an Element instance with a selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I am writing a [small library](https://github.com/kamlekar/HTML-Skinning-Boilerplate/blob/master/site/assets/js/html.js) where I am in need of selecting a relative element to the targeted element through `querySelector` method.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="relative"></div>

<!-- querySelector will select only this .target element -->
<div class="target"></div>
<div class="relative"></div>

<div class="target"></div>
<div class="relative"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var target = document.querySelectorAll('.target')[1];

// Something like this which doesn't work actually
var relativeElement = target.querySelector('this + .relative');
```

In the above example, I am trying to select the `.relative` class element relative only to the `.target` element whose value is stored in `target` variable. No styles should apply to the other `.relative` class elements.

PS: the selectors can vary. So, I can't use JavaScript's predefined methods like `previousElementSibling` or `nextElementSibling`.

I don't need solution in jQuery or other JavaScript libraries.

Comment: Is the relation always a sibling (adjacent or general) relation (or) can it be child/descendant, child of a sibling etc?

Comment: @Harry it can be anything. just like css selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way which will work for my library.

I will replace `"this "` in the querySelector with a unique custom attribute value. Something like this:

```
Element.prototype.customQuerySelector = function(selector){
    // Adding a custom attribute to refer for selector
    this.setAttribute('data-unique-id', '1');

    // Replace "this " string with custom attribute's value
    // You can also add a unique class name instead of adding custom attribute
    selector = selector.replace("this ", '[data-unique-id="1"] ');

    // Get the relative element
    var relativeElement = document.querySelector(selector);

    // After getting the relative element, the added custom attribute is useless
    // So, remove it
    this.removeAttribute('data-unique-id');

    // return the fetched element
    return relativeElement;
}

var element = document.querySelectorAll('.target')[1];
var targetElement = element.customQuerySelector('this + .relative');

// Now, do anything with the fetched relative element
targetElement.style.color = "red";
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ae7vjsoo/)**

Comment: What if I feed it the rule "this + #this.this[attr=this]"?

Comment: Here `this` is just the specific element. I can't see a reason where I will use it more than once. In this case, the string you mentioned above is invalid.

Comment: My point is, simple string replacement (regx or nor) cannot replace proper css rule parsing. "this" can be *part of* any class name, id, or attribute selectors. Of course it is your library, so you can always say you know what you need and I'll stop here.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot.**
If you insist on using the `querySelector` of the subject element, the answers is there is no way.

The spec and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) both says clearly that `Element.querySelector` must return "a *descendant* of the element on which it is invoked", and the object element you want does not meet this limitation.

You must go up and use other elements, e.g. `document.querySelector`, if you want to break out.

> You can always override `Element.prototype.querySelector` to do your biddings, including implementing your own CSS engine that select whatever element you want in whatever syntax you want.
>   I didn't mention this because you will be breaking the assumption of a very important function, easily breaking other libraries and even normal code, or at best slowing them down.

Comment: But there can always a workaround.. right? I am asking for the same.

Comment: Like I said in the JS chatroom - you can implement your own CSS engine that support `this` and override the default querySelector.  You want to do this route?

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be ideally:

```
var relativeElement = target.querySelector('.relative');
```

But this will actually try to select something inside the target element.
therefore this would only work if your html structure is something like:

```
<div class="target">
 <div class="relative"></div>
</div>
```

Your best bet would probably in this case be to use `nextElementSibling` which I understand is difficult for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
target.querySelector('.relative');
```

By using querySelector on the target instead of document, you scope the DOM traversal to the target element.
It is not entirely clear from your explanation, but by related i assume you mean descendant?

To get all target elements you can use

```
document.querySelectorAll('.target')
```

And then iterate the result